# problems injecting custom userDetailsService in Spring Security OAuth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Spring Security OAuth2 2.0.7.RELEASE. As i am using ORM to connect to my database and default JdbcUserDetailsManager uses jdbc i wanted to implement my own UserDetailsService, which is

```
@Service
public class UserService
    implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetailsService loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // I tested this logic and works fine so i avoid this lines
        return userDetailsService;
    }
}
```

Besides, i've  modified authorities schema as follows:

```
mysql> describe authorities;
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| authority_id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id      | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| authority    | varchar(256)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Then i am injecting my custom userDetailsService like this:

```
@Configuration
@Import(OAuth2SupportConfig.class)
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfig extends
        AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

  ...    

  @Autowired
  private UserDetailsService userDetailsService

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer    endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore).tokenServices(tokenService);
        endpoints.userDetailsService(userDetailsService); // Inject custom
        endpoints.authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)
            throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class AuthenticationManagerConfiguration
    extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userService;

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
 auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(this.dataSource).and().userDetailsService(this.userService);// Inject custom
    }
}
```

If i send /oauth/token request with grant_type=password then i get this error

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Authorization: Basic aW5kaXJhOnNlY3JldA==
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: c89baf37-8ad2-4270-5251-9715bfab470a
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password&username=user&password=pass
```

(where clientId and clientSecret is encoded)

```
{
  "error": "unauthorized",
  "error_description": "PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select username,authority from authorities where username = ?]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'username' in 'field list'"
}
```

Apparently is still using the default JdbcDaoImpl. In fact, when i started debugging, i found that is following these steps:

1. Authenticates client (OK, since i haven't modified oauth_client_details table)
2. Authenticates user with my custom userDetailsService(OK, users table modificated but my custom userDetailsService supports changes)
3. Authenticates user with default userDetailsService(ERROR)

I don't know why this is happening. It sounds like a bug to me.
Do you find anything wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(this.dataSource).and().userDetailsService(‌​this.userService);// Inject custom` and I here it's creating two auth managers - one with default `JdbcDaoImpl` and `dataSource` pointing to `this.dataSource` and another with your custom `userService`. Try just putting `auth.userDetailsService(this.userService)` (I hope that userService already have jdbc autowired inside).

The point here is that `.and()` is used to add different authentication configurations to the authentication manager, not configuring the `jdbcAuthentication()` one.

Answer (score 1):

In `2.0.7` when you do a `POST/GET` request on `/oauth/token` with grant type as `password`, it will actually except a `ClientDetailsUserDetailsService` but not `UserDetailsService`.

I had similar issue and this is how I solved it :

```
public class AppClientDetailsUserDetailsService extends ClientDetailsUserDetailsService {
    public AppClientDetailsUserDetailsService(ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
        super(clientDetailsService);
    }
}


public class AppConsumerDetailsService implements ClientDetailsService {

     public ClientDetails loadClientByClientId(String clientId)
            throws OAuth2Exception {
           //some logic
     }
}

<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
          entry-point-ref="entryPoint" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
            >
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="entryPoint" />
        <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />

</http>

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
      <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </bean>
```

`authenticationManager` is the bean for `AppClientDetailsUserDetailsService` whose constructor argument is `AppConsumerDetailsService`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I thought that when i did oauth/token request with grant_type password then the authenticationManager the authenticationManager was authenticating the client ( with the ClientDetailsService) in first place and then the user (with the UserDetailsService) . Appart of that, i thought that clientDetailsService just use oauth_ tables (not users, authorities and groups tables), that's why assumed that this was a problem with the UserDetailsService . Is this all wrong?

Comment: First part is correct, It authenticates client and then user. But I did not the second part of your question. By the way do you have any implementation for the `ClientDetailService`? But you have to mention mention `clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter` in order to make it work.

Comment: no, i don't. i think i should, what do you tnik?. but i can't think of the way to do the client login. i mean, i thought that it was just going to oauth_client_details, i don't understand why should it goes to users table..

Comment: @jscherman can you add the request that you are making to `/oauth/token` in the question? I will try to explain based on that.

Comment: so you have `client id` and `client secret` in the call, there should a mechanism to verify whether this is a valid client or not, for that you need a `ClientDetailsUserDetailsService`.

Comment: Yes, i understand that. what i really don't is why i cannot use default clientDetailsUserDetailsService, since i didn't modificate oauth_ tables, i think that i don't get how that client authentication works, since i have the thought that it was being done by checking the oauth_client_details (and other oauth_ tables)

Comment: Its failing on JdbcDaoImpl line 165 :             dbAuthsSet.addAll(loadUserAuthorities(user.getUsername()));
which is logical because i changed the table. but this is while authenticating the user, so i don't understand why the clientDetailsUserDetailsService problem you mentioned...

Comment: I've just editted explainign better what is happening

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using default `JdbcDaoImpl`. The query which is causing the problem is

```
public static final String DEF_AUTHORITIES_BY_USERNAME_QUERY =
        "select username,authority " +
        "from authorities " +
        "where username = ?";
```

This is used as a default query to load all authorities for the user by userName inside `JdbcDaoImpl`. So if you still want to use default `JdbcDaoImpl` - you can set the custom query, which will do the job with your tables, as the parameter of it.

I'm not sure what is the schema of you users table, but something like this should be similar(if you are configuring JdbcDaoImpl bean programmatically):

```
String query = "select username,authority " +
        "from authorities join users on users.id = authorities.user_id " +
        "where users.username = ?";
jdbcDaoImpl.setAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery(query);
```

Or if you create JdbcDaoImpl from XML:

```
<bean id="userDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
    <property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery"
              value="select username,authority from authorities
                        join users on users.id = authorities.user_id
                        where users.username = ?"/>
</bean>
```

There might be some other default queries that you would like to change to fit your schema, take a look at them inside `JdbcDaoImpl`.

You might also consider a possibility of writing your own implementation of `UserDetailsService` if it will start getting too far from default `JdbcDaoImpl` one.

Comment: Actually, that is exactly what i've done. I did my own implementation and injected it, the problem is that is still using defaults one besides my custom userDetailsService. I tried overriding query too, as you say, and happens the same:  It's still using the original, so it fails. Thanks anyways

Comment: No problem! i appreciate your response either way

Comment: I have another guess: you are using `auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(this.dataSource).and().userDetailsService(this.userService);// Inject custom` and I think here it's creating two auth managers - one with default `JdbcDaoImpl` and dataSource pointing to `this.dataSource` and another with your custom `userService`. Try just putting `auth.userDetailsService(this.userService)` (I hope that `userService` already have jdbc autowired inside).

Comment: That is a good guess.  I will try it tomorrow.  But if I take off that them I should inject a client service as well as defaulttokenservices too,  right?

Comment: it worked! you are a genius! leave your answer so i can give you the bounty points, if you want